# Saltstack retrieve IP address using mine.get

Tags: salt-stack

Am trying to create a template where it will retrieve the IP address of consul servers as DNS using `mine.get`. On command line it seems to work fine, but when used in the template context its not returning anything

Here is my setup

In /srv/pillar I added `mines.sls` and modified `top.sls` as following

mines.sls

```
mine_functions:
  network.ip_addrs: []
```

top.sls

```
base:
  '*':
    - mines
```

After refreshing pillars and using `mine.send` and `mine.update`, I could query from saltmaster server the IP addresses for consul

```
sudo salt 'redis*' mine.get 'consul*' network.ip_addrs
redis-001-stage.c.project-gce.internal:
    ----------
    consul-001-adm.c.project-gce.internal:
        - 192.16.0.1
    consul-002-adm.c.project-gce.internal:
        - 192.16.0.2
```

I tried to apply the same principle in a state file using templates

```
# Resolver Configuration
resolv-file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/resolv.conf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: '0644'
    - source: salt://resolver/files/resolv.conf
    - template: jinja
    - defaults:
        nameservers: {{ salt['mine.get']('*', 'network.ip_addrs', 'eth1').items() }}
```

and in resolve.conf

```
{%- for nameserver in nameservers %}
nameserver {{ nameserver }}
{%- endfor %}
```

but the nameservers always coming up empty, can someone advise please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've been passing the interface name `eth1` as the third parameter to `mine.get`, but this parameter is used for [the matching type you want to have for the first parameter](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mine.html).

Leave it out and you'll retrieve a list of the IP addresses. Once this returns values, I didn't manage to pass the full list of addresses to the jinja template. Instead I evaluated the `mine.get` inside the `resolv.conf` template.

This got me working:

```
resolv-file:
  file.managed:
    - name: /tmp/resolv.conf
    - source: salt://resolv.conf
    - template: jinja
```

and then

```
{%- for server, addr in salt['mine.get']('*', 'network.ip_addrs').items() %}
nameserver {{ addr[0] }} # {{ server }}
{%- endfor %}
```

By the way: you could also choose to run a consul agent locally and forward the DNS requests specific to consul to your local consul agent (that in turn resolves them from the service directory). [Using `dnsmasq` and Network Manager this might look like this script I uploaded to Github](https://github.com/ahus1/saltconsul-examples/blob/master/master/srv/salt/dnsmasq/init.sls).